# GetComputerName() returning empty Result

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i'm trying to use the GetComputerName() function in my C++ application but can't get it to work. Here is my code:

the .h:

```
#pragma once

class sample
{
public:
    sample();
    char* get_info_pcName();
    ~sample();
private:
    char* info_pcName;
};
```

the .cpp:

```
#include "sample.h"

#include <windows.h>

sample::sample()
{
    this->info_pcName = 0;
}

char* sample::get_info_pcName()
{
    if (info_pcName)
        return this->info_pcName;

    this->info_pcName = new char[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD nComputerName = sizeof(this->info_pcName);
    if (!GetComputerName(this->info_pcName, &nComputerName))
    this->info_pcName = "error";

    return this->info_pcName;
}
```

What's wrong here? I always get an empty reponse ):

Comment: `sizeof(this->info_pcName)` yields the size of `char*`, not the length of the array...

Comment: oooooh, must be the time. yes, you are right, thanks. it now returns the right length, but the result is still empty. i changed it to: "sizeof(*this->info_pcName);" which should be correct?

Comment: `DWORD nComputerName = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH;` is correct, sizeof can't help you in this case.

Comment: `sizeof(*this->info_pcName);` yields the size of `char`, i.e. `1` -- again, not the length of the array.

Comment: By the way, you can access member variables directly without using `this->`.

Comment: Also, make sure the d'tor correctly deletes the array.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(this->info_pcName)` yields the size of `char*` (probably 4 or 8 on your system), not the length of your array. The following should work:

```
char* sample::get_info_pcName()
{
    if (info_pcName)
        return info_pcName;

    DWORD nComputerName = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    info_pcName = new char[nComputerName];
    if (!GetComputerName(info_pcName, &nComputerName))
        info_pcName = "error";

    return info_pcName;
}
```

Also, it's poor practice to use raw pointers in this fashion. I would recommend the following instead for C++03 (for C++11 there are better approaches):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

class sample
{
public:
    char const* get_info_pcName();

private:
    std::vector<char> info_pcName;
};

char const* sample::get_info_pcName()
{
    if (!info_pcName.empty())
        return &info_pcName[0];

    DWORD nComputerName = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    info_pcName.resize(nComputerName);
    if (!GetComputerName(&info_pcName[0], &nComputerName))
        std::strcpy(&info_pcName[0], "error");

    return &info_pcName[0];
}
```

This way you don't need a handwritten constructor or destructor, nor a handwritten copy constructor or copy assignment operator (both of which your class incorrectly lacks, which would cause memory corruption with any normal usage).

Comment: Why bother allocating a dynamic buffer since the length is always the same anyway? declare info_pcName as `char[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1]`. BTW, using `TCHAR` or at least `wchar_t` would even be better. We're in the 21st century ;-)

Comment: @Serge : As opposed to? Returning a pointer to local data as you suggest would yield [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and if the data were statically-allocated inside of the type then the type's size would increase by `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1` bytes + padding -- not good.

Comment: OK, we're playing the nitpickers here :-) Are you afraid to go out of memory by allocating millions of occurences of a class whose purpose is to hold the computer name? I'd rather spend the additional couple of hundreds of bytes than adding additional complexity to the code, which costs time to develop, time to debug, time to test, time to explain to the client that we have a production code bug,... ;-) Also, are you sure the OP links with the STL?

Comment: @Serge : Avoiding undefined behavior is far from being a nitpicker, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

its not pretty but it works everytime. VC6++ sp6. Change X to 255 if needed. t is a CString value.

```
x = 100;
tmpBuf = (char *)malloc(x);
if(GetComputerName(tmpBuf,&x)){
    t.Format("%s",tmpBuf);
}
free(tmpBuf);
```

Use the CString t for anything you need. I'm sending it to SQL.